# how to create a table name dynamically based on the week

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to create a backup table called `pipelinebackupWk##`, where `##` denotes the current week looked up from a fiscal calendar table. For example: this week the backup table will be called pipelinebackup10, next week it will be called pipelinebackup12. I need the weeks to change automatically so that my SSIS package runs without me having to change it manually every week.

I am currently using this:

```
select * into (
    select 'Pipelinebackup'+'WK'+ RIGHT(CAST(WEEK_OF_QUARTER AS VARCHAR(2)),2) 
    From [dbo].[Fiscal_calendar] 
    Where ACTUAL_DATE = Convert(Datetime, Convert( nvarchar(20), getdate()-5,101)) 
) 
from table12
```

Comment: Where is this table used in ssis package?. can u describe? where ever it is, create a variable, dynamically make its value = table name. Use it in the package.

Comment: this week 10??? next week 12??? I probably make one backup table with week column....

Comment: I agree with @Justin, we don't have any context but it's usually bad design to have periodically named tables. Put it into one table  with another column, or if you're archiving for performance purposes, address the performance issue

Answer (score 0):

You can create the table with a stored procedure. there you write dynamically the create table string and execute it. the double exec(sp_execute) maybe not necessary, if you stay in one DB. something like this works for me, creating dynamic tables:

```
create proc [make_new_tab]
as begin 
  declare @wk as NVARCHAR(2);
  declare @SQL as NVARCHAR(MAX);
  select @wk = CAST(WEEK_OF_QUARTER AS NVARCHAR(2)) from  
    [dbo].[Fiscal_calendar] 
       Where ACTUAL_DATE =  (
                 select Convert( Datetime, Convert( nvarchar(20), getdate()-5,101)))
                 from table12)
  set @SQL = N'exec YOUR_DB..sp_executesql N''CREATE TABLE PipelinebackupKW'+ @wk + ' (Col1 INT NOT NULL, Col2 INT NOT NUL) ON PRIMARY ''
EXEC(@SQL)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do the table creation in SSIS, you could:

1. Use a Execute SQL Task to run the *look up week number in fiscal year table query*, storing the result in a variable (called, say, *WeekNumber*).
2. Use an Expression Task to build a `CREATE TABLE` statement that is stored in another variable. This expression should reference your @[User::WeekNumber] variable where you need the week number inserted. For example:  `@[User::CreateTableQuery] = "CREATE TABLE pipelinebackupWk" + @[User::WeekNumber] + " (c1 int PRIMARY KEY, ....."`
3. Use a second Execute SQL Task to run the query defined in your *create table query* variable.